# Salesforce: how to schedule a task to run on the first day of every quarter

Tags: salesforce, apex

We need to accomplish the following:

On the 1st day of each quarter, we would like to update all open opportunities that have "close date" in the past quarter and set the new "close date" to be the last day of this new quarter.

I'm new to SFDC, but from my research it seems triggers or Time-dependent workflow may not do this. Can we write and schedule a cron script to do this?

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Cross posting for [duplicate question on Salesforce Stackexchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/81599/102).

To make this a fully automated process you can combine a scheduled apex class and a batch class.

The scheduled apex class will be executed on the first day of every quarter. Once executed, it will start a batch job that will find all open opportunities that have "close date" in the past quarter. For each of those opportunities the batch job will set the new "close date" to be the last day of this new quarter.

The batch job is important to ensure it can scale as the number of opportunities increases.

For a CronExpression, try something like:

- `0 0 0 1 1/3 ? *` - Runs on the first of every third month starting January
- `0 0 0 1 JAN,APR,JUL,OCT ? *` - Runs on the first of the specified months.

See also [Apex Scheduler](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.192.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm)